# NaiveBayes Classifier

Tags: python, classification

I am having a problem with naive bayes classifier, I am trying to analyse some sentences but I have some errors in python.

```
from naiveBayesClassifier.trainedData import TrainedData

class Trainer(object):
"""docstring for Trainer"""
def __init__(self, tokenizer):
    super(Trainer, self).__init__()
    self.tokenizer = tokenizer
    self.data = TrainedData()

def train(self, text, className):
    """
    enhances trained data using the given text and class
    """
    self.data.increaseClass(className)

    tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    for token in tokens:
        token = self.tokenizer.remove_stop_words(token)
        token = self.tokenizer.remove_punctuation(token)
        self.data.increaseToken(token, className)
```

That's the error in the console: Does anyone knows how to fix the problem? Thanks

```
 tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text)
AttributeError: module 'naiveBayesClassifier.tokenizer' has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

Thats the main class:

```
   from naiveBayesClassifier import tokenizer
from naiveBayesClassifier.trainer import Trainer
from naiveBayesClassifier.classifier import Classifier


postTrainer = Trainer(tokenizer)

postsSet = [
    {'text': 'not to eat too much is not enough to lose weight', 'category': 'health'},
    {'text': 'Russia try to invade Ukraine', 'category': 'politics'},
    {'text': 'do not neglect exercise', 'category': 'health'},
    {'text': 'Syria is the main issue, Obama says', 'category': 'politics'}
]

for post in postsSet:
    postTrainer.train(post['text'], post['category'])

postClassifier = Classifier(postTrainer.data, tokenizer)

classification = postClassifier.classify("Obama is")
print(classification)
```

Comment: where is `naiveBayesClassifier` from? and how is `Trainer(tokenizer)` being called? what is `tokenizer`? like what sort of object is `tokenizer`?

Comment: naiveBayesClassifier is the folder that contains all the files. I done some updates.

Comment: inside `tokenizer.py` is there a method named `tokenize`?

Comment: yes, def tokenize(self,text):
        return text.lower().split(' ')

Comment: what's with `self` in `tokenize`? is it part of a class that isn't being imported? i'm guessing something like `from naiveBayesClassifer.tokenizer import TokenizerClass` and then `TokenizerClass().tokenize(stuff)`?

Comment: I used self to call the tokenize method. I done your changes and it is the same AttributeError: module 'naiveBayesClassifier.tokenizer' has no attribute 'tokenize'.

Comment: i dunno, can you include the contents of `tokenizer.py`, i'm having difficulty understanding what is going on.

Comment: @jmunsch I fixed it. Thanks is working now.

Comment: oh what was it?

Comment: I just imported the Tokenizer without declaring the path and I just installed the nltk.